# Strange behavior and dim lighting on a ceiling fan light

Tags: lighting

We have a ceiling fan in a room that's always had electrical problems since we moved in years ago (grounding mostly). (A few months ago we finally got a bad grounding issue fixed, or so I thought.)

The latest stupid thing going on has the LEDs bulbs I put in (multiple types!) turning on but being VERY dim. More like a night light than a room light! These are supposed to be 40W or 60W bulbs and use something like 5-7W.

So after trying 2 or 3 different brand LEDs with that same result, I decided to try an old incandescent bulb I had laying around even though I don't use those anymore. It turned on but it was also very dim, and the light was RED. This is supposed to be a regular soft white bulb. Now that bulb might be 10 or 15 years old (could that be why?) but at this point I was so confused I was going to call an electrician.

We haven't used the lights or fan in that room since then, for obvious reasons. But does anyone have any idea what the hell could be going on?

Comment: This sounds like the fan's bulb-power-limiter is failing/has failed (a known issue with reasonably recent fans)

Comment: Incandescent bulbs do not have a best by/use before date if in decent dry storage.  They only wear out/burn out with use or broken.

Comment: Ok, yeah maybe just an issue with the ceiling fan, hopefully that can be fixed...